# How does the Between operator work in dynamodb with strings

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, between

I was not expecting to get back a value from the query below.  1574208000#W2 is not between 1574207999 and 1574208001.  But the records are still returned.  Can anyone shed light on how the between comparison is done?

[image: Dynamo Screen shot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DynamoDb between operator with strings works with the lexicographic order of the strings (ie, the order in which they would appear in a dictionary). Using this order, 1574208000#W2 does fall between 1574207999 and 1574208001

Two strings are lexicographically equal if they are the same length and contain the same characters in the same positions.

Apart from that, to determine which string comes first, compare corresponding characters of the two strings from left to right. The first character where the two strings differ determines which string comes first. Characters are compared using the Unicode character set. All uppercase letters come before lower case letters. If two letters are the same case, then alphabetic order is used to compare them.

If two strings contain the same characters in the same positions, then the shortest string comes first. [Ref](https://chortle.ccsu.edu/java5/Notes/chap92/ch92_2.html)

To try this out, you can try a simple example in Java

```
String a = "1574207999", b = "1574208000#W2", c = "1574208001";
System.out.println(a.compareTo(b)); // prints negative number, indicating a < b
System.out.println(b.compareTo(c)); // prints negative number, indicating b < c
```